# Create radio button using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using **jsPdf** to generate a pdf on a client side , the documentation is really confusing me.
I want to insert a radio button on the pdf.
On the official docs there is AcroFormRadioButton Class, that list the constructor and Function Members of this classes, i am not able to create a new object using the constructor on the 
[Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpEFf.png).
i found a code that can create a new radio button, but i didn't understand it :

```
      var doc =  new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [ 595.28,  841.89])
      doc.setFontSize(10);
      doc.text(87.03635, 24.691223, 'Original');
      var radioGroup = new RadioButton();
      radioGroup.V = "/Test";
      radioGroup.Subtype = "Form";
      doc.addField(radioGroup);
      var radioButton1 = radioGroup.createOption("Test");
      radioButton1.Rect = [87.0363, 24.691223, 20, 20];
      radioButton1.AS = "/Test";
      radioGroup.setAppearance(AcroForm.Appearance.RadioButton.Circle);
      doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

on the offical docs i cant found RadioButton() constructor and the methods used to create the radiobutton, i looked on source code of jsPDF, but same issue.

Where i should look on the documentation/source of jsPdf, to understand this code.

Comment: Having the exact same problem here - the jspdf documentation and examples are not very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This demo site is super helpful - http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/

In the dropdown, select AcroForms and it runs through a quick and dirty setup for each form element.

Here's the short version:

```
/* global jsPDF */
var doc = new jsPDF();
var {
  RadioButton,
  Appearance
} = jsPDF.AcroForm;


doc.text("RadioGroup:", 50, 165);
var radioGroup = new RadioButton();
radioGroup.value = "Test";
radioGroup.Subtype = "Form";

doc.addField(radioGroup);

var radioButton1 = radioGroup.createOption("Test");
radioButton1.Rect = [50, 170, 30, 10];
radioButton1.AS = "/Test";

var radioButton2 = radioGroup.createOption("Test2");
radioButton2.Rect = [50, 180, 30, 10];

var radioButton3 = radioGroup.createOption("Test3");
radioButton3.Rect = [50, 190, 20, 10];

radioGroup.setAppearance(Appearance.RadioButton.Cross);
```

I needed to alter the imports and use of constructors a bit:

```
// import
const jsPDF = require('jspdf');
const doc = jsPDF('p', 'pt'); 

// then using the radio button constructor
var radioGroup = new doc.AcroFormRadioButton();

// and using 'appearance'
radioGroup.setAppearance(doc.AcroFormAppearance.RadioButton.Cross);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for updating the post!

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, the accepted answer does not work for ES6 (ie: Angular), we can not rely on the demo code as class name and properties are outdated.

The jsPDF documentation is accurate for ES6 use :
https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html

Here is my code:

```
import jsPDF, { AcroFormRadioButton } from 'jspdf';

const doc = new jsPDF();

const radioGroup = new AcroFormRadioButton();
radioGroup.fieldName = "group_id";
doc.addField(radioGroup);

const field = radioGroup.createOption("Test1");
field.x = 20;
field.width = 20;
field.height = 20;
field.y = 20;
const field2 = radioGroup.createOption("Test2");
field2.x = 20;
field2.width = 20;
field2.height = 20;
field2.y = 20;

radioGroup.setAppearance(doc.AcroForm.Appearance.RadioButton.Circle);
```

**Note 1:** Calling setAppearance is mandatory, if you don't call it option field will be created with undefined name, so if you want import form data after filling it you will not be able to read your radio value by code.

**Note 2:** It seems there is an error into the jsPDF type declaration because Appearance is detected as a method and not as a type by the compiler. We can ignore the compile error with @ts-ignore.